# Partial set identification

Tags: set-identification

[image]Hi,

I bought a bag of sealed LEGO from the second hand shop. It is labelled 6 so must be part of a larger set. Is anyone able to identify it?

Answer (score 6):

The "Red Support 1 x 6 x 5 Girder Rectangular" answers this.

It's only in two sets, and in [3368](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3368-1#T=I) there are 10, which your picture doesn't show, so this is probably [4430 Fire transporter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4430-1#T=I).

EDIT: There are no "Trans-Light Blue Panel 1 x 2 x 2 with Side Supports - Hollow Studs" in 3368, so this is definitely 4430.